# Programmatically-created NSWindow slow to resize

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

If I create an `NSWindow` by hand:

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 600, 500)
                                               styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:YES];
```

…then resizing it is slow and laggy compared to a window from a Storyboard. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Give the window's content view a layer:

```
window.contentView.wantsLayer = YES;
```

This is the default for Storyboard windows:

[image]

Comment: And why does that make resizing _faster_? You'd think it would actually increase the overhead.

Comment: When a non-layer-backed window is resized, the app redraws its content into a buffer provided by the window server — megabytes of uncompressed image data for all but the smallest windows. Resizing a layer-backed window may just involve changing properties of the layers that make up the window — stretch the titlebar background to the new width, set this button's position, etc. — while keeping their existing content.

Comment: It's also fun to play with its effect on memory usage. A sample app with a non-layer-backed window uses 14MB when the window is as small as I can make it, and 53MB when the window is the full size of my MBP screen. When I make the window layer-backed, it stays at 14MB regardless of the size of the window (because each pixel of the plain grey background doesn't need to be represented individually).

Comment: Fascinating. I remember when turning on layer-backing risked _breaking_ the display of certain window elements.